# How to access the inner DOM document from Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, dom, microsoft.mshtml

I've been having a lot of problems using Selenium Webdriver and I've given up using it. When I access a page with 11600 lines, it stops responding to commands like "FindElement". I would like to have access to the DOM document from the Webdriver using the DOM interfaces contained in the Microsoft.mshtml library. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: does it stop responding when you're searching for elements using just xpath or also via id?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Chrome driver.